# Viewing current users of map (mxd)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, tools

Is anyone aware of a script or tool that would allow me to view what users have a paticular mxd open at one time?

We are using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to rely on your file system for this information.

I've used [openfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490961.aspx) from the command prompt to get this information from window file shares.  You would need admin access to the actual server, so this might not be an option for you.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>openfiles

INFO: The system global flag 'maintain objects list' needs to be enabled to see local opened files. See Openfiles /? for more information.


Files Opened Remotely via local share points:
---------------------------------------------

ID       Accessed By          Type       Open File (Path\executable)
======== ==================== ========== =====================================
2433     JPC                Windows    C:\temp\checkadd.mxd
2442     JPC                Windows    \PIPE\psexecsvc
2443     JPC                Windows    \PI..execsvc-DDF-FFD-GISM-3396-stdin
2444     JPC                Windows    \PI..xecsvc-DDF-FFD-GISM-3396-stdout
2445     JPC                Windows    \PI..xecsvc-DPU-FFD-GISM-3396-stderr
```

Answer (score 4):

It used to be called the Job Tracking eXtension (JTX) but now it is called [**ArcGIS Workflow Manager**](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/arcgis-workflow-manager/index.html)

This thing does some really cool stuff. However it is a $$ hit.

If you look on the ArcScripts website I think there is a free "mini" mxd utility that does something like this.